# While Loop break stops my statement from Printing

Tags: python

(Python/PythonAnywhere)
My Code Now:

```
while True:
    try:
        Question = input("How are you? (Please answer with: ""Good, or Bad"")");
        if Question == ("Good"):
            print("Good to hear!");
            if Question == ("Bad"):
                print("I'm Sorry");
                if Question == ("Bad"):
                    print("Sorry to hear buddy")


            break;
    except:
        if Question == (""):
            print("Please type: Good, or Bad")
```

This is what goes after: (The code didn't wanna include this)

```
name = input("Enter your name: ")
print("Hello", name + "!");
```

The problem, (from what i can understand) is that the break messes with the print, "I'm Sorry" and when the loop is broken, it also stops the print from printing, moving on to asking the users name. i've attempted to change what print it blocks, but that didn't work, then i tried changing what i had indented, but that didn't help either. if anyone has an idea how to fix this, i'd love to know.

(P.S I'm a beginner, so if it's a super easy fix, don't take shots at me. i'm just trying to learn python, lol)

Comment: Does that indentation match your actual code? The second `if` will never succeed, because it's in a block where `Question == "Good"`.

Comment: What's the purpose of `try/except`? Nothing in the `try` block will raise an exception if they don't type Good or Bad.

Comment: What do you mean by "This is what goes after: (The code didn't wanna include this)"?

Comment: @blackbrandt I think he just didn't know how to include it in the same code block.

Comment: What purpose do you think the semi-colons will serve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent properly, so that each condition is tested independently.

There's no need for `try/except`, since nothing raises any conditions (this is often used when validating numeric input, since `int()` and `float()` will raise exceptions if the input isn't numeric).

You want to break out of the loop when they enter one of the valid choices.

```
while True:
    Question = input("How are you? (Please answer with: ""Good, or Bad"")");
    if Question == "Good":
        print("Good to hear!");
        break
    if Question == "Bad":
        print("I'm Sorry");
        break
    print("Please type: Good, or Bad")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to wrap my head around loops in general, and it's nice to have people willing to help some random idiot online. Thanks for help, it fixed it. have a good day

Answer (score 0):

You can read the [Python Control Flow Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html). "break", like its name, breaks the loop and finish your loop. You can use `pass` if you want to see no action, or you can use `continue` to step up the next iteration.

The difference between `continue` and `pass` is the type of going on the loop. For example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in l:
    if i > 3:
        pass
    print(i)  # output will be 1 2 3 4 5
```

Let's try this function with continue:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in l:
    if i > 3:
        continue
    print(i)  # output will be 1 2 3
```

Summarily, you can make the loop work with 2 ways:

- **continue:** Finish the loop and don't keep going the codes under it.
- **pass:** Do nothing and continue the loop and keep going the codes under it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i'll read through the article